# Add a line below each item selected in bottom navigation view

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I want to put a ligne below each Bottom Navigation View Item's items when It is selected. As the image below, but I don't find the way to do it.
I create a shape line, line.xml as the following :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:width="6dp" android:height="2dp" android:color="@color/honey"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

and I create a selector checked_uncheked.xml as the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/line" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

I added `"app:itemBackground="@drawable/line"` below the bottomNavigation and still have no result

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this `line.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="32dp"
        android:right="32dp"
        android:top="32dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="6dp" android:height="2dp" android:color="@color/honey"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Adjust the margins according to your layout.

Comment: I tried your solution but still not get what I want

Comment: @Lina Set `app:itemBackground=@drawable/selector checked_uncheked`

Comment: yes, worked thank you but still have a problem 
The line display on to the Name (Home,Account,....), how can i put it below with margin 2dp

Comment: Worked Thank you, I just change the size

Comment: Hey Lina, I am trying to achieve the same and I am not able to follow what you did. Would you mind to post the updated answer here please?